# Copying Variable Names

Tags: objective-c

```
<code>
//header file has appropriate declarations but not included here:
#import "AddressCard.h"

@implementation AddressCard;

-(NSString *) name
{
   return name;
}

//Recommended code:
-(void) setName: (NSString *) theName
{
   [name release]
   name = [[NSString alloc] initWthString: theName];
}

//Incorrect code according to Kochan:
-(void) setName: (NSString *) theName
{
   [name release]
   name = [NSString stringWthString: theName];
}

//rest of class implementation code snipped
@end

<code>
```

So I saw this code on stack overflow which is not my code and I am not trying to take it or anything but I just had a quick question regarding this piece of code in objective C. In the `(void) setName: (NSString *) theName` method why do we have to do `[name release]` and then `name = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: theName]`.

Why can't we just simply say `name = theName`. Won't that just copy `theName` variable passed as a parameter in the `setName` method into the original `name` variable?

Sorry if this is a bad question, but I am new to objective c and a little bit confused on memory management coming from a java background.

Comment: This code is very old. Memory management has changed greatly and you would no longer need to include the `release` method.

Comment: Oh I was not aware of that. So in the setName method would you simply just do name = theName; or would you just have name = [[NSString alloc] initWthString: theName]; without the [name release] code? Thank you for answering.

Comment: Both are incorrect and archaic. If `theName` is the same instance as `name` and `name` is the only pointer retaining the string the `release` will delete it before it is added. There needs to be a check that `theName` != `name`. But this is non-ARC memory management.

Comment: -(void) setName: (NSString *) theName
{
   if name == theName{return}
   [name release]
   name = [[NSString alloc] initWthString: theName];
} <br> Is this how the code should look then? </br>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct modern style is to use ARC (automatic reference counting) in your project, which is the default for new projects (and has been for a few years). Then you do not need to, and are not allowed to, send the `release` message.

The choice of `initWithString:` vs. `stringWithString:` makes no difference under ARC, and you might as well write it like this instead:

```
- (void)setName:(NSString *)theName {
    name = [theName copy];
}
```

By using `copy` (or `initWithString:` or `stringWithString:`), you ensure that your `name` won't change even if the caller passed in an `NSMutableString` and then changed its contents later.

But you probably don't even need to write a setter if you just want to do what you put in your question. All you need to do is put this in your `.h` file:

```
@interface AddressCard

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

// other declarations...

@end
```

The compiler will automatically generate an instance variable (named `_name`), a setter, and a getter for you if you omit them. However, using `strong` means the compiler-generated setter won't copy the string; it will just keep a reference to the string given by the caller.

If you want to use `copy` as I described above, declare the property like this instead:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
```

Then the compiler will generate a setter that uses `copy`.

Comment: Wow this is the most confusing language I have ever seen... I appreciate your answer greatly though. Thank you do much.

Comment: Also you mentioned that the compiler will automatically generate a setter method that uses copy by using this line of code: @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name. How do I use this automatically generated setter method since I do not know the name of this method that was created by the compiler?

Comment: The setter method will be named `setName:`.

Comment: Oh Ok. Never mind. I was able to figure out what you mean by those automatic methods that were generated by trying out an example. Anyways thank you so much for the help, it cleared up a lot of doubts. :)